# Two amsrefs bibliographies, with different label styles

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, amsrefs

How can I convince amsrefs to use in one `biblist` the alphabetic style and in another `biblist` the numeric style?

Comment: This has become a RFE on amsrefs by now, I guess. It may be useful for people looking for this, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 2.12 of 2013/01/15, `amsrefs.sty`'s `biblist` environment takes an optional argument allowing to change the label style locally, so this is now the canonical solution.

Comment: I should have asked for some form of babelization... :-)

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I managed to do this by saying

```
\makeatletter
\let\alpha@label\relax
\makeatother
```

right before the second `biblist`.

**Later:** Changing other of the formatting options would be nice, too, by the way. For example, the second `biblist` should use only initials, and that is more annoying to do: one has to copy all of this code:

```
\BibSpec{nameLE}{
  +{}{}{initials}
  +{}{\IfEmptyBibField{initials}{}{ }}{surname}
    +{}{ }{jr}
}
\BibSpec{nameBE}{
    +{}{}{surname}
    +{}{ }{initials}
}
\BibSpec{nameinverted}{
    +{} {}  {surname}
    +{,}{ } {initials}
    +{,}{ } {jr}
}
```

and using the `nobysame` option amounts to saying

```
\let\save@primary\@empty
```